# Call Refenrence Class function by string

Tags: r, reference-class

Is there a easy way to call a function of object of a reference class by string like a `do.call("...",...)` for standard functions in R?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a class and instance

```
A <- setRefClass("A",
         fields=list(x="numeric"),
         methods=list(value=function() x))
a <- A(x=10)
```

A funky way of invoking the value method is

```
> a[["value"]]
Class method definition for method value()
function () 
x
<environment: 0x123190d0>
```

suggesting that we could do

```
> do.call("[[", list(a, "value"))()
[1] 10
```

This has some pretty weird semantics -- the function returned by `do.call` seems to be independent of the instance, but actually is defined in the instance' environment

```
> fun = do.call("[[", list(a, "value"))
> fun
Class method definition for method value()
function () 
x
<environment: 0x1c7064c8>
> a$x=20
> fun()
[1] 20
```

Also, functions are instantiated in a 'lazy' way, so `a[["value"]]` only returns a function if it has already been called via `a$value()`. As discussed on `?setRefClass`, I think one can force definition of the method at the time of object initialization with

```
A <- setRefClass("A",
         fields=list(x="numeric"),
         methods=list(
           initialize=function(...) {
               usingMethods("value")
               callSuper(...)
           },
           value=function() x))
```

Comment: Many thx, till now I do not watch into the object via str or dput to see that we could access to the function via a[["value"]].